# How to make a blur transparent linear layout

Tags: android, transparent, blur

I have a transparent layout in android, and behind the layout there is an image. how to make the linear blur ? I found examples to make the image itself blur but I don't want to make whole image blue, just only the part that is behind the linear layout.

Comment: Can you please provide some screenshot of what you're trying to achieve - it will somehow help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have pretty complex solution, so there won't be any code. So, here is idea, step by step:

1. Let's assume that your layout have just single custom `LinearLayout`. No `ImageView` as a background.
2. What we going to do, is draw background drawable of `LinearLayout` by our own, so it will first draw full image and then draw blurred square from the same image on top. Content of `LinearLayout` might be moved to desired position using paddings.
3. So, create something like `MyLinearLayout` and put it to your layout resource. Provide required constructors.
4. Override `onAttachedToWindow()` and `onDetachedFromWindow()` methods. Inside them we should load our background `Bitmap` and recycle it accordingly. Let's name it `mBackground`
5. Override `draw()` method. Inside it we're going to first draw our `mBackground`.
6. Then, you can use `Canvas#clipRect()` method to crop drawing area of `Canvas` to some specified rectangle. In your case, this rectangle should be the area below your content. You can figure it out using `View#getPadding*()` methods. Don't forget to call `canvas#save()` before clipping drawing area.
7. Now you can draw your bitmap once again with blur (I don't know which method exactly you're using, so let's assume that you know how to do it... but you still can share it with us :) ). Cool thing is that you can just draw the same `Bitmap` once again in full scale - since we had called `clipRect` before, it will be drawn only within this area. Don't forget to call `canvas#restore()` after drawing background.
8. Call `super.draw()` to draw rest of the stuff, that your `LinearLayout` contains.

Answer (score 1):

Set a semitransparent Blur image to the linear layout or simplest set a color to linear layout and set it to semitransparent by defining alpha

edited solution

do this...

1.) create a blur copy of the image u have on background.
2.) clip the image by using

```
Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBmp, startX, startY, widthLayout , heightOfLayout);
```

3.) set this image in the Linear Layout using an image-view with height and width attribute as fill-parent.

Comment: yes I have used alpha to make it semitransparent but I want to make it blur !